# Can't change Movieclip's current frame while setting depths of Movieclip's children

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I'm trying to set the depth of every MovieClip contained in one big MovieClip called 'map'. 
To do this, I made a function that runs on event ENTER_FRAME, i.e :

```
public function set_depth(map:MovieClip) {
    var arr:Array = [];
    for(var i=1;i<=map.numChildren;i++) {
        arr.push({ "name" : map.getChildAt(i-1).name, "y" : map.getChildAt(i-1).y});
    }
    arr.sortOn("y", Array.NUMERIC);

    for(var h=0;h<arr.length;h++) {
        map.setChildIndex(map.getChildByName(arr[h].name), h);
    }
}
```

What the function basically does is to sort MovieClip based on its y property and set the MovieClip index
based on the ordererd list of the MovieClips (the y property would eventually change on its own so the 
index order will change too). The problem is, I can't seem to change the 'map' MovieClip frame
while the 'set_depth' function continously runs, for example I wanted to change the map current frame everytime
I pressed the Shift key which looked like this :

```
public function whenKeyUp(e:KeyboardEvent) {
    if(e.keyCode == 16) {
        trace('Shift pressed');
        map.gotoAndStop(2);
    }
}
```

Nothing's happened everytime I pressed Shift, eventhough the trace function gets called. However, if the
'set_depth' function gets commented/deleted, the map MovieClip changed its frame to 2 without any problem.

So, is there anyhting wrong with the code? Can I somehow fix it so that the map MovieClip can change
its frame while the set_depth function runs? Or is there any other solutions? Thanks in advance. Pardon my English

Comment: How MovieClips are placed inside maps. I mean how is the inside structure of map MovieClip?

Comment: It is placed just under the 'map' MovieClip, e.g: map.hero, map.dummy, map.house etc

Comment: Are they placed on different keyframes?

Comment: No, it's all on the first frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming setDepth(map) is called from function yourEnterFrame(e: Event)..

Change this to

```
public function whenKeyUp(e:KeyboardEvent) {
    if(e.keyCode == 16) {
       map.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, yourEnterFrame);
       map.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameHunt);
       trace('Shift pressed');
       map.gotoAndStop(2);
   }
}
```

And please add this

```
public function frameHunt(e: Event){
var map:MovieClip = MovieClip(e.target);  
    if( map.currentFrame != 2) return;
    map.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameHunt);
    map.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, yourEnterFrame);
}
```

Comment: The addFrameScript doesn't seem to work on this one. The 'map' MovieClip still can't change. This is weird, it shows no compile or runtime error. If you're interested, I could send you the .fla and .as via email or anything. Thank you

Comment: I changed the approach. No boolean flag this time. Just event signals. Please try it.

Comment: Thanks, will definitely try it soon as I got back home